# Create Relationships in Atlas Device Sync for SwiftUI

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction.'

I followed this [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#write-data---swiftui), which works. I ran into an error when I tried adding two relationships. See code below:

```swift
class Dog: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var owner: Person? // I believe this is causing the error
    
    convenience init(name: String = "", owner: Person) {
            self.init()
            self.owner = owner
    }
}

class Person: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var dogs: List<Dog>
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

```swift
struct AddDogToPersonView: View {
    
    @ObservedRealmObject var person: Person
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    $person.dogs.append(Dog(name: "Benny", owner: person))
                    dismiss.callAsFunction()
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss.callAsFunction()
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain what’s going on? The error says I can’t manage outside of a write transaction but it’s visible inside. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the dog has a reference to its owner. Here:

```
$person.dogs.append(Dog(name: "Benny", owner: person))
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/relationships/#inverse-relationship) "Relationship definitions in Realm Database are unidirectional." So basically the problem was that that I linked it twice!

```swift
class Dog: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name = ""
    //@Persisted var owner: Person? // I believe this is causing the error
    @Persisted(originProperty: "dogs") var assignee: LinkingObjects<Person>
    
    convenience init(name: String = "", owner: Person) {
            self.init()
            self.owner = owner
    }
}
```